# pthread_rwlock across processes: Repair after crash?

Tags: linux, locking, pthreads

I'm working on linux and I'm using a pthread_rwlock, which is stored in shared memory and shared over multiple processes. This mostly works fine, but when I kill a process (SIGKILL) while it is holding a lock, it appears that the lock is still held (regardless of whether it's a read- or write-lock).

Is there any way to recognize such a state, and possibly even repair it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real answer is to find a decent way to stop a process. Killing it with `SIGKILL` is **not** a decent way to do it.

This feature is specified for [mutexes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutexattr_setrobust.html), called robustness (`PTHREAD_MUTEX_ROBUST`) **but not for rwlocks**. The standard doesn't provide it and kernel.org doesn't even have a page on rwlocks. So, like I said:

- Find another way to stop the process (perhaps another signal that can be handled ?)
- Release the lock when you exit

Comment: I used SIGKILL specifically to test the robustness of my solution.

Answer (score 1):

@cnicutar - that "real answer" is pretty dubious.  It's the kernel's job to handle cross process responsibilities of freeing of resources and making sure things are marked consistent - userspace can't effectively do the job when stuff goes wrong.

Granted if everybody plays nice the robust features will not be needed but for a robust system you want to make sure the system doesn't go down from some buggy client process.